# Can't enable and use network instead of NetworkManager

Tags: linux-networking, centos7

I'm trying to deploy [RDO](https://www.rdoproject.org) but can't follow some of its [prerequisites](https://www.rdoproject.org/Quickstart#Step_0:_Prerequisites):

> In case your system is running with NetworkManager, you need to
>   disable it.
>
> Stop and disable NetworkManager:
>
> ```
> systemctl stop NetworkManager
> systemctl disable NetworkManager
> systemctl enable network
> ```

I can follow the first two command with no problem. However, the third one gives me a response that I doesn't understand:

```
#systemctl enable network
network.service is not a native service, redirecting to /sbin/chkconfig.
Executing /sbin/chkconfig network on
The unit files have no [Install] section. They are not meant to be enabled
using systemctl.
Possible reasons for having this kind of units are:
1) A unit may be statically enabled by being symlinked from another unit's
   .wants/ or .requires/ directory.
2) A unit's purpose may be to act as a helper for some other unit which has
   a requirement dependency on it.
3) A unit may be started when needed via activation (socket, path, timer,
   D-Bus, udev, scripted systemctl call, ...).
```

The service seems to be inactive:

```
#systemctl status network.service
network.service - LSB: Bring up/down networking
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/network)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2015-09-10 11:46:50 ICT; 28min ago
```

OS: CentOS Linux release 7.1.1503 (Core) (Minimal Installation)

Comment: I noticed this same issue. After rebooting and trying many fixes I found that the network was just being unusually slow to come up after a reboot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow, using `#chkconfig network on` works.

Answer (score 0):

This command didn't work for me i have this in my network status

● network.service - LSB: Bring up/down networking
Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/network; generated)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2022-12-01 18:58:46 EST; 7min a>
Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)

déc. 01 18:58:45 openstack.example.com systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Bring up/down >
déc. 01 18:58:46 openstack.example.com network[1498]: Activation de l'interface>
déc. 01 18:58:46 openstack.example.com network[1498]: Activation de l'interface>
déc. 01 18:58:46 openstack.example.com network[1696]: Activation de l'interface>
déc. 01 18:58:46 openstack.example.com network[1696]:
déc. 01 18:58:46 openstack.example.com network[1696]: rreur : l'activation de l>
déc. 01 18:58:46 openstack.example.com network[1498]: rreur : l'
déc. 01 18:58:46 openstack.example.com systemd[1]: network.service: Control pro>
déc. 01 18:58:46 openstack.example.com systemd[1]: network.service: Failed with>
déc. 01 18:58:46 openstack.example.com systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Bring u>

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/536485)